# Uploading an image from android to a PHP server

Tags: php, android, image, upload, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image from android to a PHP server by using MultiPartEntity but i have trouble to find the source of the problem , the progress dialog steel downloading without providing any response here my code :

```
    public String postFunction(String s_v1, String s_v2, String s_v3)
throws ParseException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(s_v1);

//required apache-mime4j-0.6, et httpmime-4.0.3
MultipartEntity  mp = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

mp.addPart("choix", new StringBody("2"));
boolean exists = (new File("/data/data/my.package/files/avatar.jpg")).exists();  
if (!exists){

    Log.i(TAG,"no file");

} 
else
{
File tempImg = new File("/data/data/my.package/files/avatar.jpg");
FileBody bin = new FileBody(tempImg, "image/jpg");
mp.addPart("photo_r", bin);
}
mp.addPart("myString1", new StringBody(s_v2,  Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));
mp.addPart("myString2", new StringBody(s_v3, Charset.forName( "UTF-8" )));

httppost.setEntity(mp);
Log.i(TAG,"start ");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
Log.i(TAG,"end");
return response;
}
```

i don't know where's the problem !!
many thanks befor ;)

Comment: it works when i remove the section of file transfert , is the file declaration correct ?? help me please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved, it was because of my low internet connection, now I try to limit the connection time with SocketTimeoutException that is generated in the emulator, but unfortunately not in my phone acer liquid!